# How to interpret RMSE with scaled values vs ground truth values

Tags: machine-learning, rms, scaled

I've trained an LSTM model and am measuring RMSE. I know how RMSE is interpreted normally, but I'm a a little confused on how to interpret the RMSE value when I have scaled my features and target values.

For example, when I train my model with inputs as they are normally I get an RMSE value of around 50. But, when I scale my values between 0 and 1 with Standard Scaler I get better results, at least according to my plots of predicted vs actual values. When I scale my values I get an RMSE of around 0.1. Now, I understand why this value is much lower than an RMSE of 50, since I've scaled my values between 0 and 1. But, how do I interpret the RMSE value of 0.1 to a more accurate representation of the error I get once I've scaled my values back, because I know my error is definitely not 0.1 on normal values.

Comment: you just multiply it by the inverse of whatever you multiplied the data by during your [0,1] transformation, namely $(\max-\min)$ giving $0.1\times(\max-\min)$ and interpret it per usual :)